# Facebook sharing website customization

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hello I'm creating a website which basically has a few photos on it. I have a problem with sharing on facebook. I know about the og tags etc but this is something more in depth in my opinion.

So when I share something from imgur it looks like this [image: this]. That is thanks to the og tags.

But when I want to share something from Instagram or Flickr it looks different [image: that] . can you see the difference? There is just the photo and barely any text. It is more focused on the photo then on the metadata if you get me.

I think it has to do something with Facebook applications? If someone has any experience with this please reply :)

Comment: The imgur link have og:type=article. And flickr is using og:type=flickr_photos:photo

Comment: thank you! another question. the og:type "flickr_photos:photo" is a custom option for flickr right? is there a possibility or a must for creating like "mywebsite:photo" og:type?

Comment: Just create your own open graph object type